# python how to create automatically terminating child thread if parent thread is not alive

Tags: python-2.7

How can I create a python program  that will generate a number of child thread . 
main thread & child thread are executing  in parallel . child thread need to check 
periodically if the  parent is alive  or not  if not alive the all the  child process should terminate itself .

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the reference given by `threading.currentThread()` from the parent to the child thread and periodically check whether the parent is still alive.

```
import threading
import time


class Child(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent_thread):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        #self.daemon = True
        self.parent_thread = parent_thread

    def run(self):
        while self.parent_thread.is_alive():
            print "parent alive"
            time.sleep(.1)
        print "quiting"

Child(threading.currentThread()).start()
time.sleep(2)
```

As a second alternative you can call `self.parent_thread.join()` to wait blocked for that thread to finish.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join

Or you can set the child thread to `daemon` mode, but the whole process will terminate if there are only daemon threads alive. Thats not necessarily what you want for a graceful shutdown.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon

Answer (score 1):

You should you the `daemon` property of a Thread object, like this:

```
import threading
import time

def worker():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('doing work')

t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

EDIT: To use several threads, you can create a list of threads:

```
my_threads = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    my_threads.append(threading.Thread(target=worker))
    my_threads[-1].daemon = True
```